# Parse API change, PFLogInViewController not found

Tags: ios, parse-server, pfloginviewcontroller

Getting back to an Objective C project of mine started a while ago , which was compiling fine, I now find myself with a few issues related to `Parse` pods. Searching the net I already found a few things, but still have some problems (and doubts).

First I got an error message saying that a file was not found on this line:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

After reading a few related post, I understood that `ParseUI` was deprecated and I should use `Parse/UI` instead in my `Podfile`, so I changed the line above to:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

And I also changed in the `Podfile`:

```
pod 'ParseUI'
```

to:

```
pod 'Parse/UI'
```

I then reran:

```
pod install
```

But I now have these messages showing up:

```
Cannot find interface declaration for 'PFSignUpViewController', superclass of ....
No type or protocol named 'PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate'
.....
Cannot find interface declaration for 'PFLogInViewController', superclass of ....
```

along the project.

And I was indeed subclassing PFSignUpViewController as well as PFLogInViewController.
So where did those classes go? Deprecated, different names or what?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

.......

After making a separate new project to check how things work, I found out that I can still use PFLogInViewController. And then looking again on the net for posts about similar issues, I tried to add this line:

```
@import Parse;
```

But I get this error:

```
Module 'Parse' not found
```

I must be doing something wrong hiding the `PFLogInViewController` class.

Comment: I don’t believe there have been any changes to the names of the classes you are using. The fact that you are getting the error saying that Parse isn’t found suggests an issue with your cocoa pods or maybe you have other errors in the project that are preventing the Parse SDK from building properly.

Comment: Well, you may be right, but I am investigating the issue, by making a simple example project using PFLogInViewController. At this point I have made something working in Swift. But in Objective C I have some issues and get this message: "Use of undeclared identifier 'PFLogInViewController'". Do you know what I need to import to get the PFLogInViewController definition.
I have already:
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
and also tried:
#import <Parse/ParseUI.h>
But it is not working. I guess I am missing something.

Comment: I can use PFObject and write things to the server, but can't get PFLogInViewController to work in Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a separate small project to isolate the problem, I first hit the same issue. And with a bit more digging I ended up solving it by adding this import:

```
#import <PFLogInViewController.h>
```

after the one which was already there:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

I hope this can help someone else having the same problem at some point.